# Client connection timeout during Android & Windows PC communication via sockets

Tags: android, c, sockets, winapi

I'm currently trying to make my android device and windows PC communicate with each other via sockets.

I have a problem with a connection between my android device and windows PC. Client side connection timed out. (errno 101)

I selected the android device as 'client' and the windows PC as 'server'

Here is my code for Android(client) [Using NDK]:

```
#define SOCKET_SERVER_IPV4_ADDR "24.133.169.180" //External IP of my windows PC (server to connect)
#define SOCKET_CONNECTION_PORT 307 (Connection port)

JNICALL extern "C" int Java_com_example_pulsarspy_MainActivity_connectionTest(JNIEnv *env, jobject /* this */){
    int connectionResult, sockFd;
    sockaddr_in serverAddr;

    sockFd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if(sockFd == -1)
        return errno;

    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(SOCKET_SERVER_IPV4_ADDR);
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(SOCKET_CONNECTION_PORT);

//ACTIVITY STUCKS IN HERE THEN RETURNS TIMEOUT AFTER A FEW MINUTES
    connectionResult = connect(sockFd, (sockaddr*)&serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));
//.....................................

    if(connectionResult == -1)
        return errno;
    else return 0;
}
```

Code block which initializes the server for communication (Windows PC) [Using Win32API]:

```
//CREATE SERVER SOCKET
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
if (serverSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    printf("Socket Initialization Failed. Error Code: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(serverSocket);
    return -1;
}
printf("Socket Successfully Created.\n");

//INITIALIZE SOCKET SERVER ADDRESS TO BIND
serverAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
serverAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.0.30");
serverAddress.sin_port = htons(307);

//BIND SERVER IP WITH SOCKET
bindResult = bind(serverSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&serverAddress, sizeof(serverAddress));
if (!bindResult)
    printf("Binding completed for the server.\n");
else {
    printf("Binding Socket Failed. Error Code:%d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(serverSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return -1;
}

//START LISTENING FOR CLIENTS
if (!listen(serverSocket, 1)) {
    printf("Listening for the clients.....\n");
}
else {
    printf("An Error Occurred During Client Listening. Error Code:%d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(serverSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return -1;
}
```

My server side runs properly and starts listening.
But the client one hangs in the connect() call and returns timeout after few minutes.

I have tried searching a lot on how to communicate (transfer small amounts of data as strings) between multiple devices located in different locations using different networks via sockets, but I haven't really gotten a solution. Is there a way that I can do this?

Comment: How did you git the "external IP"? Are you sure the IP is the one of your PC and not of the WiFi NAT router providing network access to your home?

Comment: If the Android device and the PC are connected to the same LAN network (via Ethernet or Wifi), then the client needs to `connect()` to the server's LAN IP (`192.168.0.30`), not to your public/external WAN IP (`24.133.169.180`). Most routers don't support "hairpining" (ie, a LAN device connecting to the WAN IP to bounce back into the LAN). Also, why are you using Android's NDK to access the underlying socket API instead of using Android's own `Socket` class? Also, your NDK code is leaking the socket descriptor if `connect()` fails. You need to `close()` the descriptor if `socket()` succeeds

Comment: You not only should tell that you wanna use sockets but also if Android device used mobile connection or wifi.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau 1- I tried when they are in different networks. 2- Practical purposes. I'm an system programmer who have been developing low level apps for android so I'm trying to learn NDK/Android API therefore I think it's better practice to use POSIX layer instead of higher ones. 3- I was already aware but I hadn't worked on that because it wasn't my core focus. Thanks for your intention anyway.

Comment: @TarıkEsen 1) if that is the case, then you need to configure **port forwarding** on your router's WAN IP if you haven't already. 4) Why are you hard-coding the IPs? Try binding the server to `0.0.0.0`, and subscribing to a public DynDns service to give your External IP a static hostname that the client can resolve at runtime using `getaddrinfo()`.

Comment: Let me bottom line it for y'all. This external IP belongs to my NAT router (Public IP related to my network) but I forwarded port 307 to the windows PC's internal IP address(192.168.0.xx). Shouldn't it have worked when I send a data packet with port 307+external ip from a device within an other network? Was there anything else that I should've done?

Comment: In theory yes. And you can use a packet sniffer like Wireshark on your LAN to verify that.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau 1- I've already done it as I wrote above. 4- Iwill try it additionally. Thanks.

Comment: @TarıkEsen I'm out. Good luck

Comment: @Remy Lebeau I don't need any luck. I just needed some help. Some help without passive-aggresive judgements. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not passing judgement. I offered multiple things for you to look at and you shot them all down. I have nothing further to offer.

Comment: I didn't shot any offers down. I was just trying to hide too fundamental details which I've already known to help you to be more focused on the exact point which I actually needed help on it. But you claimed this benefical abstraction as my lack of detail and started complaining about it inexplicably. That's what I meant by saying "judgement". I didn't mean any of your offers by this (That's what I've already thanked for them all by the way.)